# Error on deploying simple contract : It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it it may consume all the gas you send

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mist, gas-limit

My smart contract code is here

```
// To specify what version of compiler this code will compile with
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract tokensale {

  // Declaring the maximum number of tokens available for sale.
  uint public maxTokens = 10000;

  // The number of tokens you can buy for one wei (Solidity converts all unitless values from ethers to wei).
  // We will keep the default currency to be wei. It will get clearer.
  uint public tokenSwap = 10;

  // This variable, initially set to zero,  stores the number of tokens that have been bought, i.e it will
  // get incremented each time someone buys tokens.
  uint public supply = 0;

  // mapping is an equivalent to associative array. We store token balances corresponding
  // to each address that buys tokens in this mapping.
  mapping (address => uint) balance;


  // A modifier checks if a condition is met before executing a function.
  // This  modifer checks if there are tokens available before the buyTokens function is called.
  modifier isTokenAvailable () {
    require (msg.value*tokenSwap + supply <= maxTokens);     // require checks the condition and the function that
    _;                                                       // follows, denoted by the '_', is only run if the condition
  }                                                                      // is satisfied.


  // A function to check the ether balance of any address.



  // To check the token balance of any address. The external keyword allows the function
  // to be called from outside the contract. If no keyword is specified, all functions are external
  // by default..
  function balanceOf (address tokenHolder) external constant returns (uint) {
    return balance[tokenHolder];
  }

  // A function to buy tokens accesible by any address
  // The payable keyword allows the contract to accept ethers
  // from the transactor. The ethers to be deposited is entered as msg.value
  // (which will get clearer when we will call the functions in browser-solidity)
  // and the corresponding tokens are stored in balance[msg.sender] mapping.
  // underflows and overflows are security consideration which are
  // not checked in the process. But lets not worry about them for now.

  function buyTokens () external
  payable 
  isTokenAvailable {
    uint tokensAmount = msg.value * tokenSwap;    // At this point, msg.value is in wei.
    balance [msg.sender] += tokensAmount;
    supply += tokensAmount;
  }
}
```

When I  deploying this code it shows me the error

> it seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it it may consume all the gas you send

I'm not sure what is wrong in this contract code. I have tried with different gas amount lower to higher but still same error.

Here is the output
[image]

Comment: So does the transaction fail if you execute it? What is the value you are passing?

Comment: @MuhammadAltabba No, Contract is deploying successfully but when I try to send some ETH on the contract address then the transaction getting failed

Comment: And why it is showing the RED error on deployment time ?

Comment: Can you share the deployment code (or how exactly do you make the deployment - is this Mist?)

Comment: @MuhammadAltabba My code is already in my question. Yes I'm using MIST

Comment: I am asking about the "deployment" code (not Smart Contract code) if there is any? I understand now that you are using UI to make deployment with no deployment code. Ok

Comment: Sorry I don't know how I can check "deployment" code. @MuhammadAltabba Do you have any working UI code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74197/discussion-between-muhammad-altabba-and-vikujangid).

Answer (score 3):

1. Your contract is missing the [constructor function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/contracts.html?highlight=constructor#creating-contracts).
2. If you send along some ETH with the contract creation, your constructor needs to be marked payable.
3. Use this code only for learning purpose, a good practice is using the SafeMath library for adding values to prevent overflows. In this case though this should not be that relevant.